# NameError : is not defined em python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, undefined

Estou com um problema simples, quando executo essa função ela retorna um erro :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     file.py3 on line ?, in getUserOutputs
>       userOutput = _runwwmdh(testInputs[i])
>     file.py3 on line 15, in _runwwmdh
>       return aux1 + aux2
>   NameError: name 'aux1' is not defined

Qual problema enfrento ? e como soluciono ?

```
def perfectCity(departure, destination ):
    aux1 = 0
    aux2 = 0



    if departure[0] > destination[0]:
        aux1 = departure[0] - destination[0]
    else:
        aux1 = destination[0] - departure[0]
    if departure[1] > destination[1]:
        aux2 = departure[1] - destination[1]
    else:
        aux2 = destination[1] - departure[1]
return aux1 + aux2
```

Comment: Primeiro confirme se a indentação do código aqui na pergunta corresponde à que tem no seu editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O único problema que vejo no código é que a indentação do `return aux1 + aux2` está desalinhada.

O python, ao contrário de outras linguagens (e.g. PHP), o espaço é importante, e é isso que define os blocos da linguagem, não chavetas.

Este exemplo para mim funciona.

```
def perfectCity(departure, destination ):
    aux1 = 0
    aux2 = 0

    if departure[0] > destination[0]:
        aux1 = departure[0] - destination[0]
    else:
        aux1 = destination[0] - departure[0]

    if departure[1] > destination[1]:
        aux2 = departure[1] - destination[1]
    else:
        aux2 = destination[1] - departure[1]

    return aux1 + aux2

perfectCity([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1])

''' retorna 2
```